# How to add events to a Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I want to add circles to my Jquery calendar. Each circle represents an event of a day. Each day can have at most 4 events.

Thats what I have done: http://jsfiddle.net/5bjkfrpz/1/

For example, in my example if you look at the 18/04/2020, you can see a red circle under the day. I want to put the dot circle inside the day square and under de number.

On the 18/04/2020 i have declared two events:

```
events[new Date("04/18/2020")] = new Event("Payday", "dot_blue");
events[new Date("04/18/2020")] = new Event("Bills", "dot_red");
```

Also how I can have more than one circle on each day? Because in my example it only shows the last event assignation.

I have upload a photo of what I amb trying to do (day 30/04/2020 where I have added with photoshop trhee different circles)

[image]

Comment: I think you should design these dots in photoshop and inline that as background squares.

Comment: @Rebwar there is no way to do it via CSS?

Comment: maybe you can do these but must create 3 CSS class and your elements at least have 3 CSS class but with one picture you just justify it on your element as background.

Comment: but i can create a cointaner class for example? something like this: events[new Date("04/18/2020")] = new Event("Payday", "cointaner dot_blue");

Comment: bro, just add the picture with 3 dots and it's simply work